# Using Left Join based on date tables condition so that know who employees is absent

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, ms-access-2007, left-join

I have two table From `microsoft Access Database` like this

1.HR_Personnel

```
+-----+----------+----------------------+
| ID  | NIP      | Name                 |
+----------------+----------------------+
| 1   | 200      | Teguh                | 
| 2   | 201      | Supomo               | 
| 3   | 203      | DHINI ADHITYAS M     | 
| 4   | 204      | Dhani Amanda         | 
+-----+----------+----------------------+
```

TA_Record_Info

```
+---------+-----------------------+
| Per_Code| Date_Time             |
+---------+-----------------------+
| 3       | 2013-02-20 07:45:57   | 
| 2       | 2013-02-20 07:46:13   | 
| 1       | 2013-02-20 08:48:07   | 
| 1       | 2013-02-20 15:53:40   | 
| 3       | 2013-02-20 16:01:02   | 
| 2       | 2013-02-21 07:31:57   | 
| 3       | 2013-02-21 07:39:29   | 
| 3       | 2013-02-21 15:51:47   | 
| 2       | 2013-02-21 16:11:21   | 
| 2       | 2013-02-22 07:47:45   | 
| 1       | 2013-02-22 07:53:31   | 
| 3       | 2013-02-22 16:01:43   | 
| 2       | 2013-02-22 16:11:19   | 
| 1       | 2013-02-22 16:15:26   | 
+---------+-----------------------+
```

Expected Result **EDIT**

```
+-------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| NIP   | Nama            | adate       | InTime      | OutTime     |
+-------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 201   | Teguh           | 2013-02-20  | 08:48:07    | 15:53:40    |
| 202   | Supomo          | 2013-02-20  | 07:46:13    | -           | 
| 203   | DHINI ADHITYAS M| 2013-02-20  | 07:45:57    | 16:01:02    |
| 204   | Dhani Amanda    | 2013-02-20  | -           | -           |
| 201   | Teguh           | 2013-02-21  | -           | -           |
| 202   | Supomo          | 2013-02-21  | 07:31:57    | 16:11:21    | 
| 203   | DHINI ADHITYAS M| 2012-08-21  | 07:39:29    | 15:51:47    |
| 204   | Dhani Amanda    | 2013-02-21  | -           | -           |
| 201   | Teguh           | 2012-08-22  | 07:53:31    | 16:15:26    |
| 202   | Supomo          | 2012-08-22  | 07:47:45    | 16:11:19    | 
| 203   | DHINI ADHITYAS M| 2012-08-22  | -           | 16:01:43    |
| 204   | Dhani Amanda    | 2013-02-22  | -           | -           |
+-------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I have try with this Query **EDIT**

```
SELECT p.NIP AS NIP,
        p.Name AS Nama,
                                Format (a.Date_Time, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as adate,
                                IIF((Min(a.Date_Time) <> Max(a.Date_Time)),
                                    Format (Min(a.Date_Time), 'hh:mm:ss'),
                                    IIF( Format (Min(a.Date_Time), 'hh:mm:ss') < '12:00:00',
                                         Format (Min(a.Date_Time), 'hh:mm:ss'), 
                                        '-'
                                       )
                                   )as InTime,
                                IIF((Max(a.Date_Time) <> Min(a.Date_Time)),
                                    Format (Max(a.Date_Time), 'hh:mm:ss'),
                                    IIF( Format (Max(a.Date_Time), 'hh:mm:ss') > '12:00:00',
                                         Format (Max(a.Date_Time), 'hh:mm:ss'), 
                                         '-'
                                       )
                                    )as OutTime
                                FROM HR_Personnel AS p 
                                LEFT JOIN TA_Record_Info a 
                                ON p.ID = a.Per_Code  
                                GROUP BY p.Per_Code,
                                p.Per_Name,
                                         Format (a.Date_Time, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
                                Order BY Format (a.Date_Time, 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
                                            Right(p.Per_Code,2),
                                            p.Per_Name
```

but the results display like this **EDIT**

```
+-------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| NIP   | Nama            | adate       | InTime      | OutTime     |
+-------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 204   | Dhani Amanda    |             |             | -           |
| 201   | Teguh           | 2013-02-20  | 08:48:07    | 15:53:40    |
| 202   | Supomo          | 2013-02-20  | 07:46:13    | -           | 
| 203   | DHINI ADHITYAS M| 2013-02-20  | 07:45:57    | 16:01:02    |
| 202   | Supomo          | 2013-02-21  | 07:31:57    | 16:11:21    | 
| 203   | DHINI ADHITYAS M| 2012-08-21  | 07:39:29    | 15:51:47    |
| 201   | Teguh           | 2012-08-22  | 07:53:31    | 16:15:26    |
| 202   | Supomo          | 2012-08-22  | 07:47:45    | 16:11:19    | 
| 203   | DHINI ADHITYAS M| 2012-08-22  | -           | 16:01:43    |
+-------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I think the results of my query as it caused by i left join using

> ON p.ID=a.Per_Code

**EDIT**
so teguh are not present at 2013-02-21 date is not displayed. Table only shows Dhani Amanda who was absent from the date 2013-02-22 - 2013-02-22 in overall.

I just wanted to show employee roomates table is not present in all the particular date or Dates marked with Intime and OutTime empty

Finnally what must i change from my query? I hope you can help me. thanks.

**UPDATE**

I was wrong.I write upside down between the table result and expected result table.And then the result table not present `Teguh` as employees who are not present.I have change my explain.
And then in the query

```
SELECT p.NIP AS NIP,
        p.Name AS Nama,
```

change by

```
SELECT p.NIP AS NIP,
        p.Name AS Nama,
```

I have edit my question with `EDIT` tag. thanks.

Comment: So the question is; why does Dhani Amanda keep showing up, and always with a 2013-02-20 date? Are you POSITIVE there isn't a record for this person in TA_Record_Info?

Comment: Also `p.Per_Code AS NIP` on the first line of your `SELECT` seems wrong as Per_Code does not exist in the table `P`/`HR_Personnel`. It needs to be `p.ID` or `a.Per_Code`, but most likely the first because of the `LEFT JOIN`. Same thing for the `Group By`.

Comment: To user2088176:I have edit the query

Comment: To Johnny Bones: yeah in my tables `TA_Record_Info` there are not records for Amanda Dhani but I still want show it as an employee who is absent with tables display the name and date are not present but with Intime and outtime empty.In addition I also want employees who do not attend on a particular date then Time Out In Time is not considered Absent

Comment: To All: I was `wrong`.I write `upside down` between the `table result` and `expected result table`. And then in the `query`
`SELECT p.NIP AS NIP,
        p.Name AS Nama,`
change by
`SELECT p.NIP AS NIP,
        p.Name AS Nama,`I have Edit my Question. See my Update Question. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English grammar if you do not know what I am explaining, you can ask again. I will explain as much detail as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got this line of code:
Format (a.Date_Time, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as adate,

And you're expecting to get a date for a person who has no dates associated with them in table a.  The only way that's going to work is if you create a new query (or SELECT statement) that selects the unique dates from table a, and NOT JOIN that back to table p.

Try running this, and then see if you can build the rest of your query off it.  I'm a little swamped at work, but you should be able to take it over the finish line.

```
SELECT QueryDate.ID, QueryDate.NIP, QueryDate.nama, QueryDate.adate, IIf((Min(TA_Record_Info.Date_Time)<>Max(TA_Record_Info.Date_Time)),Format(Min(TA_Record_Info.Date_Time),"hh:mm:ss"),IIf(Format(Min(TA_Record_Info.Date_Time),"hh:mm:ss")<"12:00:00",Format(Min(TA_Record_Info.Date_Time),"hh:mm:ss"),'-')) AS InTime, IIf((Max(TA_Record_Info.Date_Time)<>Min(TA_Record_Info.Date_Time)),Format(Max(TA_Record_Info.Date_Time),"hh:mm:ss"),IIf(Format(Max(TA_Record_Info.Date_Time),"hh:mm:ss")>"12:00:00",Format(Max(TA_Record_Info.Date_Time),"hh:mm:ss"),'-')) AS OutTime
FROM QueryDate LEFT JOIN TA_Record_Info ON (QueryDate.adate=DateValue(TA_Record_Info.Date_Time)) AND (QueryDate.ID=TA_Record_Info.Per_Code)
GROUP BY QueryDate.ID, QueryDate.NIP, QueryDate.nama, QueryDate.adate;
```

I have a separate query called QueryDate which consists of:

```
SELECT HR_Personnel.ID, HR_Personnel.NIP, HR_Personnel.Name as nama, QDt.UniqueDate as adate
FROM HR_Personnel, (SELECT DateValue([Date_Time]) AS UniqueDate
FROM TA_Record_Info
GROUP BY DateValue([Date_Time])) AS QDt;
```

You can probably combine the two if you try hard enough.

Comment: Hai Johnny bones sorry to interrupt your work.I want to ask, I have included a code that is used to display InTime and OutTime to the code that you provide. But still Not Work. can  you  help me to out from my problem Johnny Bones?

Comment: You can see my experiment query code in [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/18750)

Answer (score 1):

### Problem Has Solve.

This Code show employee is not present in spesific Dates or ALL Dates marked with Intime and OutTime empty.

```
SELECT QueryDate.HR_Personnel.ID, 
    QueryDate.HR_Personnel.Per_Code, 
    QueryDate.HR_Personnel.Per_Name, 
    QueryDate.QDt.UniqueDate, 
    IIf((Min(TA_Record_Info.Date_Time)<>Max(TA_Record_Info.Date_Time)),Format(Min(TA_Record_Info.Date_Time),"hh:mm:ss"),IIf(Format(Min(TA_Record_Info.Date_Time),"hh:mm:ss")="",Format(Min(TA_Record_Info.Date_Time),"hh:mm:ss"),IIf(Format(Min(TA_Record_Info.Date_Time),"hh:mm:ss")<"12:00:00",Format(Min(TA_Record_Info.Date_Time),"hh:mm:ss"),'-'))) AS InTime,
    IIf((Max(TA_Record_Info.Date_Time)<>Min(TA_Record_Info.Date_Time)),Format(Max(TA_Record_Info.Date_Time),"hh:mm:ss"),IIf(Format(Max(TA_Record_Info.Date_Time),"hh:mm:ss")="",Format(Min(TA_Record_Info.Date_Time),"hh:mm:ss"),IIf(Format(Max(TA_Record_Info.Date_Time),"hh:mm:ss")>"12:00:00",Format(Min(TA_Record_Info.Date_Time),"hh:mm:ss"),'-'))) AS OutTimeFROM (
    SELECT HR_Personnel.ID, HR_Personnel.Per_Code, HR_Personnel.Per_Name, QDt.UniqueDate
    FROM HR_Personnel, (SELECT DateValue([Date_Time]) AS UniqueDate FROM TA_Record_Info GROUP BY DateValue([Date_Time])) AS QDt
)as QueryDate 
LEFT JOIN TA_Record_Info 
ON(QueryDate.QDt.UniqueDate=DateValue(TA_Record_Info.Date_Time)) AND(QueryDate.HR_Personnel.ID=TA_Record_Info.Per_Code)
GROUP BY QueryDate.HR_Personnel.ID, 
    QueryDate.HR_Personnel.Per_Code, 
    QueryDate.HR_Personnel.Per_Name, 
    QueryDate.QDt.UniqueDate
ORDER BY QueryDate.QDt.UniqueDate;
```

Credit to [johnny-bones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2174085/johnny-bones) who want to take the time to solve my problem.

Comment: I'm not really clear why you unselected my answer, yet you used it in your own post and gave me credit for it?  If it was the best answer, re-awarding me the checkmark would be appreciated.

Comment: I am sorry johnny bones, i not understand the use of accepted answer. Because my post before someone warns me about choosing the correct answer accepted. Sorry if I'm wrong.  I have Reaccepted your answer.