# Database design for weekly time tracking

Tags: ms-access, database-design

I am planning on creating a database to track user's time in/time out M-F.  Every week should begin on monday and run through sunday.

I have a table filled with my entire user population, so I know which users I need to create entries for and where they belong to.  I have proposed so far, a table consisting of the following fields to track the entries (along with example data to fill the fields):

```
Field Name in table (Example of possible data)
---------------------
Employee (John Smith) 'String
Unit (Quality Assurance) 'String
WeekOf (9/9/13) 'date

InMonday (6:30) 'string, validate either a time in/out or N/A if holiday/vacation
OutMonday (3:15) '^^
HoursWorkedMonday (8.00) 'total hours worked
VacationMonday (0.00) 'if N/A for time, should have hours here
OvertimeMonday (0.00) 'any additional work hours should go here
```

For this instance, I would have to create In/Out for each day of the week (and perhaps track the date that each day is for). Is this extraneous or is there a seemingly better organization to tracking weekly time measurements?  Should I use one table with a unit indicator or multiple tables for each unit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually it's one table with a Date field, an In field and an Out field.  That's pretty much standard timesheet data.  Take a look at how [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18353581/using-left-join-based-on-date-tables-condition-so-that-know-who-employees-is-abs/18363162#18363162) has it set up.

Make sure you're using an Employee ID in the timesheet, and then you would have a corresponding Employee table with all relevant info (ID, Name, Address, whatever else you store on him/her).

Comment: Ah I see, then I can join that other data then when I need to. So pretty much each user should have a daily time kept. So if I enter a week at a time, I should generate a weeks worth of records for my users and then devise a way to pull them into my front end for editing.  Should I split this into tables of "units" or keep the unit as a field in the main table?  How do you deal with the manageability, there will be a lot of users, for example.

Edit: by lots, I mean a couple hundred per day

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you ultimately want to do with the data.  If you're talking about storing hours instead of actual Time In/Time Out, then I'd store the actual units instead of those fields.  Just one field "TimeWorked" and then have them input the number of hours.  As far as editing that data once it's in the database (as opposed to just adding a new record), you could transpose the data and then write it back in, cell by cell.  In general, you don't want to create an open connection to your data, ALWAYS use unbound forms.  It makes it harder to write junk records to your table.

Comment: Sorry, I mean, when it comes to creating the actual tables, how should I group my data into tables. Say I work in the "Parts Department" should I have a table for the "Parts Department", "Commission Department", etc. or should this be a field name "DEPARTMENT" in a single table in order to track the time. IE, I think I would need a union query if I wanted to see all the data in one, if its split, vs the data being in one table with a "department" field.

Comment: I would think, for scalability's sake, having one table with a Department field would make sense.  That way, if more departments are added or any are removed, you don't have to go crazy admin-ing the DB.

Answer (score 1):

While this project is technically feasible, I have to question the value of making it yourself in Access.

1. The main issue is with security:

   - As a **desktop program**, this can be very easy to hack without precautions.  Keep in mind that with Access, the user interface and the designer interface are by default the same thing.

     - If this is going to be a simple, straightforward db, a motivated user just needs to open the navigation panel and they can add/edit/delete all the timesheets.
     - If you hide the navigation panel, the user can just do a quick google search and learn to hit F11 (or find it by accident, either way)
     - You can try regularly (daily? hourly?) transferring the data from the publicly accessible back-end to an archive db that is not accessible to the general users.  This can work, but still gives them a window to edit records. And if you don't do the transfer right, they can still add old records.
   - As a webform on a **SharePoint**, this can be fairly secure. I'd recommend this if you have Sharepoint.
2. You should also consider your development time.  This is a *very* common business task across many industries, from restaurants to factories to schools.  As such, there's a huge number of cheap web-based options already out there that you can start using *today*. I'll even assume some of these include summary reviews breaking out numbers by departments as well.

   I've never researched these myself, but a quick google search found this interesting page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_time_tracking_software

Comment: I did not specify, but I will be doing this in vb.net, disconnected with a password on the database.  Better than the current situation of a bunch of excel spreadsheets.  The data acts as a verification of manual sheets.  Thanks for the links, I will take a look now.

Comment: That does sound better (I was picturing a standalone db on a shared drive). As for the links, I kind of like the ones that don't even require user input. You could just measure the hours between first mouse click and last mouse click of the day.

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain? I'm always open to new ideas.